# "TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly" Can anyone see what will fix my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, raspberry-pi3

I am fairly new to python as my school teaches visual basic using the .NET framework and I recently got a Raspberry Pi 3B+.
I am trying to create a program that I was recently asked to create on Visual Basic. 
I have looked at other forms on this TypeError but cannot see a way to fix my code.

```
Ending = ["ing","end","axe","gex","goh"]

while True:
    try:
        NameNumber_Input = input("Enter Number of Names To Be Created: ")
        NameNumber = int(NameNumber_Input)
        print(NameNumber_Input +" Users Will Be Created")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input, Please Try Again")
    else:
        break

Names=[]
for i in range (NameNumber):
    data=input("Enter Name: ")
    Names.append(data)

for i in range (NameNumber):
    print("Name: "+Names[0:NameNumber])
    import random
    for x in range(1):
        EndingNumber = random.randint(0,4)
        print("Username: "+str(Names[0][0:3])+str(Ending[EndingNumber]))
```

The Purpose is to have an inputted number of "Usernames" Created from the first 3 letters of the entered names and have one of the endings randomly selected to be put at the end of the three letters.

**These are the lines With Errors**
print("Name: "+Names[0:NameNumber])
print("Username: "+str(Names[0][0:3])+str(Ending[EndingNumber]))
**This is the Error**
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: `for x in range(1):` is a useless loop.

Comment: Thank you, I have now removed this, I am still having an issue with my TypeError, I am not entirely confident in python and don't fully understand the error, would you be able to provide an explanation? "TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly" Error for print("Name: "+Names[0:NameNumber])

Comment: You should use the [PEP8](https://pep8.org) naming convention: variables in lowercase (snake_case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make two changes in your code `print("Name: "+Names[i])` instead `print("Name: "+Names[0:NameNumber])`
and `print("Username: "+str(Names[i][0:3])+str(Ending[EndingNumber]))` instead `print("Username: "+str(Names[0][0:3])+str(Ending[EndingNumber]))`

Answer (score 1):

- Cause:

```
    Names = []
    print("Name: "+Names[0:NameNumber])
```

The `Names` here is a list type. You are add a string to a list. Python must make explicit type convertion and add operatoration between string and list is not allowed. So raise Type Error.

- Fix:
  I guess you are tring to go throught the Names and print element out.

```
    print("Name: "+Names[i])
```

But the program you write has some other logic/data structure problems so it cannot results corrcectly I think. I suggesut you read some python tutorials first to have a basic understanding of python data structure...

Comment: Thank you, Do you know of any tutorials that include examples? I have been considering buying a book or two but I am not sure of any.

Comment: @Frazzled  Python Official Documents is a good start: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/, especially chapter 3-5 will help understand and resolve this program. Also you can search `python tutorials` on youtube to get  some video tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you want the *i*th name (the name at index *i*).

Replace by:

```
for i in range(NameNumber):
    print("Name: " + Names[i])
```